# Same vue code from html not working in blade file

Tags: vue.js, laravel-blade

below is the code from html:

```
<div id="app">
    <select @change="onSelectUserType()" v-model="type">
        <option value="">Who are you?</option>
        <option value="tailor">Tailor</option>
        <option value="store">Store</option>
        <option value="customer">Customer</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            type: ''
        },
        methods: {
            onSelectUserType: function () {
                console.log(this.type)
                alert(this.type)
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('mounted');
        }
    });
</script>
```

this is code from html that is working, when i apply it inside blade it is not working! it should show alert and console on changing the options, but nothing is visible, also no error is detected what is the issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? You should provide more details on your issue.

Comment: There must be some error in the console? Could you please share that. "not working" doesn't explain a lot.

Comment: it should show alert and console on change the options, but nothing is visible, also no error is detected

Comment: Check with @input

Comment: Could you look up the source code using Ctrl + U, and post it here?

Comment: @input results same, not working